# Adapting my new Script invalid column and not return a correct expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a previous script that makes many calls to the database with a "for" in code, I change the logic, store everything in a temporary table and I am joining the data with `"#cellInfoToDelete"`, I have these error on the new script:

> Msg 8133, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> At least one of the result expressions in a CASE specification must be an expression other than the NULL constant
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
> Invalid column name 'SchedID'

Old script:

```
UPDATE
    _PS_SCHEDULES_Details_CellInfo2
SET
    EmpNumDay1 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 1 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay1 END,
    EmpNumDay2 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 2 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay2 END,
    EmpNumDay3 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 3 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay3 END,
    EmpNumDay4 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 4 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay4 END,
    EmpNumDay5 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 5 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay5 END,
    EmpNumDay6 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 6 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay6 END,
    EmpNumDay7 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 7 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay7 END,
    NotUsed1 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed1 END,
    NotUsed2 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed2 END,
    NotUsed3 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed3 END,
    NotUsed4 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed4 END,
    NotUsed5 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed5 END,
    NotUsed6 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed6 END,
    NotUsed7 = CASE WHEN @WeekDay = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed7 END
WHERE
    ID = @SchedID
```

New script:

```
UPDATE
    PSDetails
SET
    EmpNumDay1 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay1, cellToDel.EmpNumDay1),
    EmpNumDay2 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay2, cellToDel.EmpNumDay2),
    EmpNumDay3 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay3, cellToDel.EmpNumDay3),
    EmpNumDay4 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay4, cellToDel.EmpNumDay4),
    EmpNumDay5 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay5, cellToDel.EmpNumDay5),
    EmpNumDay6 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay6, cellToDel.EmpNumDay6),
    EmpNumDay7 = COALESCE(PSDetails.EmpNumDay7, cellToDel.EmpNumDay7),
    NotUsed1 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed1, cellToDel.NotUsed1),
    NotUsed2 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed2, cellToDel.NotUsed2),
    NotUsed3 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed3, cellToDel.NotUsed3),
    NotUsed4 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed4, cellToDel.NotUsed4),
    NotUsed5 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed5, cellToDel.NotUsed5),
    NotUsed6 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed6, cellToDel.NotUsed6),
    NotUsed7 = COALESCE(PSDetails.NotUsed7, cellToDel.NotUsed7)
FROM 
    _PS_SCHEDULES_Details_CellInfo2 AS PSDetails
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 1 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay1,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 2 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay2,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 3 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay3,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 4 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay4,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 5 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay5,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 6 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay6,
         CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 7 THEN NULL END as EmpNumDay7,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 1 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 2 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 3 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 4 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed4,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 5 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed5,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 6 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed6,
         MAX(CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 7 THEN 1 END) as NotUsed7 
     FROM 
         #cellInfoToDelete cellToDel) cellToDel ON PSDetails.ID = cellToDel.SchedID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of lines of code which look like this:

```
 CASE WHEN cellToDel.WeekDay = 1 THEN NULL END
```

But the error states, "At least one of the result expressions in a CASE specification must be an expression other than the NULL constant". For all of your lines like this, the only result expression you are providing is `NULL`, which is the "null constant". So you have not met the requirements for a valid `case` expression.

I think you want this:

```
UPDATE   ps        
SET      EmpNumDay1 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 1 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay1 END,
         EmpNumDay2 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 2 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay2 END,
         EmpNumDay3 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 3 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay3 END,
         EmpNumDay4 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 4 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay4 END,
         EmpNumDay5 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 5 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay5 END,
         EmpNumDay6 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 6 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay6 END,
         EmpNumDay7 = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 7 THEN NULL ELSE EmpNumDay7 END,
         NotUsed1   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed1 END,
         NotUsed2   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed2 END,
         NotUsed3   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed3 END,
         NotUsed4   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed4 END,
         NotUsed5   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed5 END,
         NotUsed6   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed6 END,
         NotUsed7   = CASE WHEN c.WeekDay = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NotUsed7 END
from     _PS_SCHEDULES_Details_CellInfo2 ps
join     #cellInfoToDelete               c  on  ps.ID = c.SchedID
```

But I'm not sure what you `max()` functions are trying to do.

Comment: The UPDATE statement only updates each matching row once. If the JOIN generates multiple rows, an arbitrary row is chosen for the update.

Comment: @CoolLife I'm aware, but the OP hasn't indicated how `#cellInfoToDelete` is populated, so it's not clear whether that will do what they want.